# Bronto Extension for magento

Tags: magento, bronto

Hey guys am using Bronto Extension for my site.i have a query that is it possible to trigger all mails from bronto rather magento example(Customer relationship management,Promotions)

Comment: Is this a programming-related question?

Comment: yes,is it possible to trigger all CRM emails from Bronto

Comment: You need to show us the code that you're having trouble with.

Comment: I have gone through the extension from magento connect they haven't specified anything regarding my query.i need to know whether it is a configuration or coding part

Comment: Stack Overflow is a programming-related Q&A site. You should only post here when you know it is a programming problem you have.

Comment: You should post to the Stack Overflow sister-site http://magento.stackexchange.com/.